# Resampling Method , Bootstrapping

Tags: bootstrap

I am currently reading the book called “Intro to Statistical Learning”. Here, it firstly generates new samples by  simulation (1000) to get population mean and then estimates std.err. But then states that

> In practice, we can not generate new samples from original population ...

and chooses “Bootstrapping”.

In this approach we obtain distinct samples by repeatedly sampling from the original (real) data set and this approach allows some observation to be repeated more than once in a given sample.

So, my question is that  don't we follow the same procedure in the “bootstraping” because here we also somehow generate new samples from the data implementing some kind of simulation? What does it mean (the sentence quoted above)? Consequently, what is the difference?

Source -- *The introduction to statistical learning, Chapter 5.2, page 188-189*

Comment: Bootstrapping resamples your sample, so you will only get units that are already in your sample. You will never get any new values with bootstrapping.

Comment: Your quote is imprecise, it should be *"In practice, however, the procedure for estimating SE(ˆα) outlined above
cannot be applied, because for real data we cannot generate new samples
from the original population. However, the bootstrap approach allows us
to use a computer to emulate the process of obtaining new sample sets, so that we can estimate the variability of ˆα without generating additional
samples. Rather than repeatedly obtaining independent data sets from the
population, we instead obtain distinct data sets by repeatedly sampling
observations from the original data set."*

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation user297.. .I got it.